# Get Resultset From Query without Meta Information Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to Node.js/Sequelize.js. I have following piece of code for query:

```
var agent_list =  models.agent.findAll({
                                      subQuery: false,
                                      where:   qry_filter,
                                      attributes: select_attributes,
                                      include:include_models,
                                      group: ['agent_id'],
                                      order: agent_data.sort || appConfig.DEFAULT_AGENT_SORT,
                                      limit: agent_data.num_results || appConfig.DEFAULT_RESPONSE_SIZE

                                    })

                                   .then(function(agent_list){

                                      console.log(agent_list);

                                   });
```

The statement "console.log(agent_list)" prints the data retrieved from db plus the meta information like options:{...} , modelOptions: {...} etc. dataValues object contains data that i want.  The resultset is nested js objects, each has the same structure so it would be very difficult to loop through the resultset and get only the dataValues.

I have experience working with PHP where something like this 
**$db -> Execute("$qry")** would return resultset with meta and to get rows 
**$db -> Execute("$qry")->getRows()** can be used.  How to achieve this in sequelize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a npm package called [sequelize-values](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-values) which you can use.

So in your case, your code would be

```
models.agent.findAll({
    subQuery: false,
    where: qry_filter,
    attributes: select_attributes,
    include: include_models,
    group: ['agent_id'],
    order: agent_data.sort || appConfig.DEFAULT_AGENT_SORT,
    limit: agent_data.num_results || appConfig.DEFAULT_RESPONSE_SIZE
}).then(function(agent_list) {
    return agent_list.map(function(agent) {
        return agent.getValues();
    });
}).then(function(agent_list) {
    console.log(agent_list);
});
```

Comment: I have implemented your solution with a bit modification.
         `then(function(agent_list){
                                          agent_list.map(function(agent) {
                                          console.log(agent.getValues());
                                          }); });`
It is working great. Exactly what i needed.

Comment: Well, if you only want to log them maybe you should consider using forEach instead. Map function actually expects you to return something as the result of the map operation

Comment: I've found stringifying then parsing the JSON results from sequelize has the same effect as sequelize-values module. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))`

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize does not use concepts like resultsets or rows. It's an ORM, so rows (including nested associations) are treated as objects with nested objects as appropriate. It also applies an "Active Record" pattern, so each returned object has additional method added to it, like "save", "update", "delete" and more.

When Sequelize instances are serialized to JSON, they strip all the Sequelize "metadata" properties and just return simple objects, as you would expect.

Also, Sequelize instances make use of property getters and setters to transparently behave like simple JS objects. This means you can do something like `agent_list[0].myProperty = 1; console.log(agent_list[0].myProperty);` and it will behave like you expect. The reason it does this is so it can keep track of updated values, so later "update" calls will only update the columns that have changed.

You should have no need to manually get the "rows" from the query result.

Comment: Yes toJSON strips all the meta information, but i need to do further processing on result before converting to JSON.
I have 95 columns in table. Calling get method for each attribute would be too cumbersome.

Comment: My point is that you don't need to explicitly call .get() or .toJSON() in order to process anything. You can just map properties (columns) of each object (row) to properties of your desired output object. E.g. `var output = { outProp: input.columnA + input.columnB);`, where "input" is an instance of a Sequelize model (row).

Comment: What i am currently doing is findAll returns all data rows +  meta data. I am using _.omit() inside toJSON method to omit columns that i don't need in response. Then as above answer suggest i am using sequelize-values to map the output. is this a bad practice? I am still learning node.js/sequelize.js